# Does $f_n(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n}}$ converge uniformly to $|x|$ and why?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

It is easy to see that  $f_n(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n}}$ converge pointwise to $|x|$

> Question: is the convergence uniform?

**Attempt:**

---

Want to show $\forall \epsilon > 0$, ... , $|f_n(x) - f| < \epsilon$

$|f_n(x) - f| = |\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n}} - \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}|$

Take $x  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

$|f_n(x) - f| = |\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n}} - \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}| = (1-1/\sqrt{2})n$

So $(f_n)$ fails to converge uniformly, can someone confirm?

Also, can someone spot the place where uniform convergence fails for the above sequence in the accompanying figure below?
[image]

Comment: You take the seùence of $x$ indexed with the same $n$ as the sequence of functions. This does not make sense. Instead, take $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$, and  keep $n$ fixed, if you will search for a counterexample.

Comment: I find $f_n(1/\sqrt{n})=\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$. This is consistent with uniform convergence (in the sense that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x_n)=f(x)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}}-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}}\right|=\left|\frac{x^2\left(\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\sqrt{x^2}}\right|\leq \left|\frac{x^2\left(\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right)}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}}\right|$$
$$=\left|\sqrt{x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}\right|=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}},\,\forall x\in\mathbb R$$
In the last line we used the inequality $\sqrt{a+b}\leq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b},\,\forall a,b>0$ for $a=x^2,\, b=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Your \big's should be \left's and \right's.